# Issue with chrome animating width of rotated elements with css gives weird triangles

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-transitions

When I try to animate the width of an absolute positioned element inside a rotated element it leaves weird triangles. Like this:
[image]

They are different every time and it only happens in chrome. It works in Firefox and safari.

```
body,html{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.container{
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
     -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    margin-left:-50vw;
    margin-top:-50vh;
}
.stripe-container{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
     -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.stripe-background{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    webkit-transition: width 900ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: width 900ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: width 900ms ease-out;
    transition: width 900ms ease-out;
}
.stripe:hover .stripe-background{
    width: 100%;
    webkit-transition: width 900ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: width 900ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: width 900ms ease-out;
    transition: width 900ms ease-out;
}
.stripe{
    height: 20%;
    position: relative;
}
```

[Link to JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1j13zc3x/)

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved this by setting `backface-visibility: hidden;` on the background element.